# ibm-cloud-private dashboard first record does not look like a TLS handshake

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I'm trying to use ibm-private-cloud dashboard to install ibm-chart.
And after selecting any chart, and proceed to configure, I'm pressing "install".

Then i got the following error in the bottom of the page:

> Internal service error : rpc error: code = Internal desc = connection
>   error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: tls: first
>   record does not look like a TLS handshake"

Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

May be try to use http_s_:// when making api requests or opening the web-interface

Comment: i found that on SF too, but it's not a common request to service, it's a service buildin dashboard